# Specific Conversion to key value pair

Tags: typescript

In typescript,I have an Object:

```
{Apple: Array(3),Orange: Array(2),Guava: Array(2), Kiwi: Array(2)}

Apple : (3) ['Doctor', 'Keep', 'away']
Orange : (11) ['sour', 'sweet']
Guava : (2) ['sweet', 'seeds']
Kiwi : (2) ['Sour', 'VitaminC']
```

I have to make this like:

```
[Apple:Doctor],[Apple:Keep],[Apple:away],[Orange:sour],[Orange:sweet]......
```

I tried using Maps..Map.entries

Comment: What is `[Apple:Doctor],[Apple:Keep],[Apple:away]...`? A string?

Comment: Please consider rewriting this to be a [mre] with valid JS/TS. Right now you're either pseudocode or maybe console output, and so we have to guess at what you're looking for. You should change the input to a valid JS object literal, and the output to... whatever it's supposed to be. (Are any of [my guesses](https://tsplay.dev/WkkeLW) correct?). Once you do this you will have an answer quickly. If you do that and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me. Good luck!